# ArrayLists and char fields

Tags: java, polymorphism

My Question is how can I use the char field to describe a genre if genre is multiple characters ex: Spy or Humor. Since a char is only 1 character how does this work?

I need a char field inside my Novel class, which can describe the genre of the novel.

Below is my code followed by the random data I created in a file "books.dat"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File("books.dat");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    while(s.hasNext()){
        if(s.nextInt() == 0){//novels
            //create novel book
            Novel n = new Novel();
            read(s, n);
            n.code = 0;
            Book.totalPages(n.pages);
            books.add(n);
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++){
        print(books.get(i));
    }
}

public static void read(Scanner sc, Novel no){
        no.name = sc.next();
        no.pages = sc.nextInt();
        no.genre = sc.next().trim().charAt(0); 

//Im having scanner take 
//the first letter of the genre and record it, 
//but there will be a problem when two genres 
//start with the same letter, how can i distinguish between the two?

}


public static void print(Book b){
    if(b.code == 0){
        System.out.printf("Name:%-15s Pages:%-10d Genre:%-10s \n",
            b.getName(), b.getPages() );
    }
}
}




public class Book {

String name;
int pages;
int code;
static int total = 0;

public Book() {
pages = 0;
name = "";
code = -1;
}

public static void totalPages(int pages){
    total += pages;
}

public int getPages(){
    return pages;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

}




public class Novel extends Book {

public char genre;


public Novel(){
}

public char getGenre(){
    return genre;
}
}
```

0 Thunderball 245 Spy

0 Goldeneye 289 Spy

1 Airplanes 456 Aviation 250

0 Jocularity 198 Humor

1 Football 434 Sports 400

1 Golf 432 Sports 307

I want this output:

Name:Thunderball          Pages:245   Genre:Spy

Name:Goldeneye            Pages:289   Genre:Spy

Name:Airplanes            Pages:456   Subject:Aviation     Illustrations:250

Name:Jocularity           Pages:198   Genre:Humor

Name:Football             Pages:434   Subject:Sports       Illustrations:400

Name:Golf                 Pages:432   Subject:Sports       Illustrations:307

Total pages:2054

Comment: Why does it have to be a `char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char in java can hold only a single character. There are 2 alternatives in this case as,

1) change type of genre from char to String, so that it can hold multiple characters like Humor etc.

2) change type of genre to char[]

Comment: make it an array? then would i store each individual letter in a new array index?

Comment: Right, if char[] genre holds value[H,u,m,o,r].  You can get character value with help of index. genre[0] will return you with 'H' and genre[1] will return you with 'u' and likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Scanner class (you are using for reading) provides function *nextLine()* which returns String. This may by what you are looking for. Of course, in this case, the file "books.dat" should be organized in a way that each title is on a separate line.

Actually I prefer *DataInputStream* and *DataOutputStream*, that have *writeUTF()* and *readUTF()* for reading/writing Strings.

```
DataInputStream  reader = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStrean(fileName));
```

then

```
int a = reader.readInt();
String genre = reader.readUTF();
```

etc